# Set default selected option in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am using the latest design support library. And I have set up the navigation view with four fragments as its menu items.

I would like to have my first fragment (i.e first item in the navigation drawer)opened when the user starts the app.

By default it shows me the MainActivity layout.

I tried

```
navigationView.getMenu().getInt(0).setChecked(true);
```

But the above code does not do anything.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/navigation-drawer-how-set-selected-item.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you use fragment container layout? If not, add this to your `activity_main.xml`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your Activity override `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Instead of `MainActivityFragment()` call your fragment which you want to display at the beginning.

Comment: Yes I am using container. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Note, you should put the `replace()` call within a `if (savedInstanceState == null)` check - otherwise your fragment will be replaced on rotation.

Answer (score 8):

```
navigationView.getMenu().getInt(0).setChecked(true);
```

replace by

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```